# $p$ be a prime number , $G$ be a group of order $p+1$ such that $\exists f \in Aut(G)$ of order $p$ , then is $G$ abelian and has prime exponent?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

Let $p$ be a prime number , $G$ be a group of order $p+1$ such that there exists $f \in Aut(G)$ of order $p$ ; then is it true that $G$ is abelian and there exist a prime number $q$ such that $g^q=e , \forall g \in G$ ?

Comment: I see someone was kind enough to provide you with a downvote without explanation. Have a compensatory upvote, on me. :)

Comment: @DustanLevenstein : Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Note that $f$ permutes the $p$ nontrivial elements of $G$, so it must form a $p$-cycle, i.e., it cycles all nontrivial elements of $G$. Let $q$ be a prime factor of $p+1$ and let $g \in G$ be an element of order $q$, which exists by Cauchy's theorem. Then $\{f^i(g) \mid 0 \le i < p\} = G-\{e\}$ implies that every nontrivial element of $G$ has order $q$, i.e, the exponent of $G$ is $q$.

By Cauchy's theorem, this implies $|G| = q^k$ for some natural number $k$, so $Z(G) \neq \{e\}$. Let $h \in Z(G)$ be a nontrivial element. Then, once again, $f$ carries $h$ to all other nontrivial elements of $G$, so we get $Z(G) = G$.

Comment: @downvoter why... ?

Comment: I thought this would be self-explanatory, but [here you go](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16341/what-to-do-when-other-users-answer-low-quality-questions). It would be nice if you didn't provide compensatory upvotes for (imo) undeserving posts, either.

Comment: @epimorphic Compensatory upvotes is not something I've made a habit of doing (in fact, I'm pretty sure that's the first time I've done it); it was just a way of responding to the fact that *some* users (apparently, yourself included) think it's acceptable to downvote a post without providing an explanation. It's not, and I wish this website didn't make it so easy. There was nothing wrong with the question; it's not a trivial result, and I provided a perfectly good explanation of how to prove it. If you had an issue with the question, you should have made an appropriate comment and close vote.

Comment: I guess you're not familiar with OP, but he's been prompted multiple times within the last month to provide evidence that he's made good-faith attempt at solving these homework-type questions, and as we see here he continues to ignore that quite regularly. What is one more comment going to do?

Comment: @epimorphic It would provide context for other users. Such as myself.